# THREE.js static scene, detect when webgl render is complete

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am creating a static scene with a lot of objects and I want to save as image after it is rendered. How do I do that in THREE.js r69?

Comment: Did the answer you accepted actually answer the question and solve your problem? Because my saved images have timing issues using the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, you are not going in the right direction.

if you have some function like this

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render ();
}
```

The render is doing it's work all the time.

When you are seeing the scene *unfinished*, it's because the meshes haven't finished loading, not because the render hasn't finished rendering.

So, you have to listen for some onload event on the models that you are loading, that will depend on the method that you use to load them (and that you don't explain, so I can't help you more)

Given the code in your reply, it isn't clear when you add the mesh to the scene. Anyway, I would try something in the line of

```
function loaderCallback() {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh (...
    scene.add (mesh);
    requestAnimationFrame(saveImage);
    render ();
}
```

the function invoked at requestAnimationFrame should be called when render finishes.

Comment: I use JSONLoader to load an exported 3D Studio Max object that has textures: var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "js/cabinet_with_texture_2.js", function ( geometry, materials ) {
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );