# when scene is really rendered out using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm making a progress bar such as "loading" in a scene with three.js.
But when is the scene really loaded?Render is doing its work all the time and the Loader's callback option just work when the images get loaded from network.And i can't find a callback function option where the scene is really loaded or rendered out.
So where or when is the callback function should be called?

Comment: The scene doesn't load. External assets might, but the scene itself does not.

Comment: i'm using render like this   function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render ();
}

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara sorry,i use wrong word.I just want to know when is the whole scene rendered out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318854/three-js-static-scene-detect-when-webgl-render-is-complete

Comment: What do you mean "the whole scene rendered out"? After `animate` runs the first time?

Comment: no,i mean all the objects in the scene display

Comment: Well, your code will be responsible for adding the objects and rendering them. Just keep track and do whatever it is after that.

Comment: Thank you.But it doesn't work.If i add it right after the render() ,the loading disappears before the scene shows.I think its because render works all the time while the scene may not finish.I can't figure out when the scene is finished.

Comment: http://krpano.com/tours/paris/ i just want to make the same loading with three.js

Comment: What needs to be loaded? Your background image? You need to be more specific for others to be able to help you with this.