# Callback function first time render out to call in three.js?

Tags: three.js, render

I want to know when is the first time all the object are rendered?  Is there any callback function option?

It seems that there is only a callback function available for image loading.

I want to hide something after all the objects are rendered. Could anyone tell me when my function to do this hiding should be called?

The render works all the time, but I don't know when is the first time all the objects in my scene are rendered.

Comment: Your logic will determine this. Keep track of everything loading, keep track of everything being added to the scene. Then on the next render pass should be the first time everything is rendered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [when scene is really rendered out using three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229618/when-scene-is-really-rendered-out-using-three-js)

Comment: You're right,i add the code.As render() works all the time,i add a flag to track the first time.It works but still not perfect.The function is called right before everything is rendered.

Comment: Then try it on the seconds render call maybe

Comment: Or don't even call render until all things are loaded unless you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

As the image is ajax loaded,i should have a flag on the loadTexture callback funtion.That may be the key.

```
 THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(this.scenedata.urls[i],THREE.UVMapping,function(){
        self.isLoaded=true;

      })
```

in the update()

```
if(this.isLoaded) this.hideLoadingbar()
```

It works better,just after image loaded and before everything is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Images sometimes take some time to load, but everything else will be in place when the first animation frame is executed. So in your animation code, just check if this is the first time it is called, and hide your object at that point.

Comment: " but everything else will be in place when the first animation frame is executed." This is not necessarily the case. He may be loading many other assets other than images and it will depend on when he starts the render loop.