# How to start a timer when a three.js render is visible to the user

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm building an application for performing Psychometric Visual Search tests.  For example, I'll render a bunch of 'L''s on the screen and, optionally a 'T'.  The challenge is to measure the time from the moment the image has been drawn to the monitor, until a key-press from the user indicating a decision as to whether a  "target" is present in the image or not.

I'm using Three.js (rather than a 2D library) as I want to evaluate search performance when the scene is rendered orthographically (traditional pyschometric 2D visual search) AND when rendered in perspective as, for example, an educational game might be.  Targets/distractors will be 3D cubes, polyhedrons, or text (ie L's and T's) may 50 of them max, so not a very complicated scene at all.

I did spot a prior Q/A where the the goal was to determine when a render was finished so the image could be saved.   Adapted for my needs it might look something like this..

```
function init() {...

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh (...  //build the targets and distractors
    scene.add (mesh);
    requestAnimationFrame(startTimerWaitForKeyDown);
    render ();
}
```

Am I correct in my understanding that my startTimerWaitForKeyDown function will get called AFTER the initial render () of the scene has been synced to the screen, as an indication that the browser is ready to render a second frame, and that readiness to render the second frame is implicit evidence that first frame is finished and has been synced to the monitor?

I'm never rendering a second frame..just trying to start a timer at the moment the first render is visible to the test subject...(or the best proxy thereof).

Accuracy to a millisecond or two is fine...I'm just trying to avoid the 16.66ms of render/frame-sync uncertainty.

Thanks!

JD

PS.   the prior Q/A is here

[THREE.js static scene, detect when webgl render is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318854/three-js-static-scene-detect-when-webgl-render-is-complete)